# Error Code: 1292 Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '358.93601676744487'

Tags: mysql, sql

Hei, i've some problems according to my query can anyone help me. Here di SQL script :

The condition was :

- The datatype (in table) several in varchar, several in integer, several in double.

And what i want is to fullfill this result in one click.

```
INSERT INTO fix_table
SELECT * , numerator/denumerator AS result
FROM (
    SELECT * , 
    (field_1+field_2+field_3) AS numerator,
    (weight_1 + weight_2 + weight_3) AS denumerator

    FROM (
        SELECT * ,
        CASE
            WHEN `download_throughput_kbps` = "NULL" THEN 0
            WHEN  CAST(`download_throughput_kbps` AS UNSIGNED) >= 5000 THEN 100*5
            WHEN  CAST(`download_throughput_kbps` AS UNSIGNED) >= 3000 THEN 80*5
            WHEN  CAST(`download_throughput_kbps` AS UNSIGNED) >= 1500 THEN 60*5
            WHEN  CAST(`download_throughput_kbps` AS UNSIGNED) >= 700 THEN 40*5
            WHEN  CAST(`download_throughput_kbps` AS UNSIGNED) >= 200 THEN 20*5
            WHEN  CAST(`download_throughput_kbps` AS UNSIGNED) < 200 THEN 0
            ELSE 998
        END AS field_1,
        CASE
            WHEN  `upload_throughput_kbps` = "NULL" THEN 0
            WHEN  CAST(`upload_throughput_kbps` AS UNSIGNED) >= 2941 THEN 100*5
            WHEN  CAST(`upload_throughput_kbps` AS UNSIGNED) >= 252 THEN 80*5
            WHEN  CAST(`upload_throughput_kbps` AS UNSIGNED) >= 39 THEN 60*5
            WHEN  CAST(`upload_throughput_kbps` AS UNSIGNED) >= 16 THEN 40*5
            WHEN  CAST(`upload_throughput_kbps` AS UNSIGNED) >= 3 THEN 20*5
            WHEN  CAST(`upload_throughput_kbps` AS UNSIGNED) < 3 THEN 0
            ELSE 998
        END AS field_2,
        CASE
            WHEN  `response_delay_ms` = "NULL" THEN 0
            WHEN  CAST(`response_delay_ms` AS UNSIGNED) < 190 THEN 100*5
            WHEN  CAST(`response_delay_ms` AS UNSIGNED) < 270 THEN 80*5
            WHEN  CAST(`response_delay_ms` AS UNSIGNED) < 420 THEN 60*5
            WHEN  CAST(`response_delay_ms` AS UNSIGNED) < 800 THEN 40*5
            WHEN  CAST(`response_delay_ms` AS UNSIGNED) < 2460 THEN 20*5
            WHEN  CAST(`response_delay_ms` AS UNSIGNED) >= 2460 THEN 0
            ELSE 998
        END AS field_3
        CASE
            WHEN `download_throughput_kbps` = "NULL" THEN 0
            ELSE 5
        END AS weight_1,
        CASE
            WHEN `upload_throughput_kbps` = "NULL" THEN 0
            ELSE 5
        END AS weight_2,
        CASE
            WHEN `response_delay_ms` = "NULL" THEN 0
            ELSE 5
        END AS weight_3
        FROM sometables
        WHERE `datehourss` = "2020-10-06%"
    ) AS new_table
) AS new_table_2;
```

sorry still new bie

Comment: Show `CREATE TABLE` scripts for `fix_table` and `cei_daily_2`.

Comment: Create a table which stores ranges and according scoring and join it to data source (avoid CASEs). ```WHERE `datehourss` = "2020-10-06%"``` is incorrect, use comparing with 2 datetime literals. ```WHEN `download_throughput_kbps` = "NULL"``` compares not with NULL but with 4-char string `'NULL'`.

Comment: *Error Code: 1292 Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '358.93601676744487'* I think that you try to store the result of `numerator/denumerator AS result` expression which is DOUBLE into INTEGER column, and server SQL mode is strict. Use explicit casting to legal value (CAST, ROUND, etc.).

Comment: Okey... i'll try your suggestion Akina. Thank you.